# Typescript: Add method to array of a class

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, model

Let's say I have an Article model which has one field with the name of the article in different languages:

```
class Article {
  constructor(public name: Translation[]) { }
}

class Translation {
  constructor(
    public language: string,
    public text: string
  ) { }
}
```

I'd like to be able to call a method to translate that article name to the language given as an argument:

```
article.name.translate('EN')
```

How could I add that method to that array of translations?

Comment: Instead of `Translation[]`, you may want to create a custom collection (perhaps `TranslationCollection`. Otherwise, create a **getter**, making `name` either private or protected.

Comment: First I though about creating a collection, but I would have to define a property in it so I would have to do something like article.name.translations.translate('EN') , wouldn't I? How would I use the getter? I cannot pass an argument to it, can I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**V1:**

```
class Article {
    constructor(public name: Translation[]) { }

    public translate(language:string):string {
        return this.name.find(t=>t.language==language).text;
    }
}


class Translation {
    constructor(
        public language: string,
        public text: string
    ) { }
}

let a = new Article([
    new Translation('EN', 'Yes'),
    new Translation('DE', 'Ja')
]);
a.translate('EN');
```

**V2:**

```
class Article {
    constructor(public name: TranslatableProperty) { }
}

class TranslatableProperty {
    constructor(public propTranslation:Translation[]) { }   

    public translate(language:string):string {
        return this.propTranslation.find(t=>t.language==language).text;
    }

}

class Translation {
    constructor(
        public language: string,
        public text: string
    ) { }

}

let a = new Article(new TranslatableProperty([
    new Translation('EN', 'Yes'),
    new Translation('DE', 'Ja')
]));
a.name.translate('EN');
```

Comment: I thought about this, but the problem that I see is that I have more classes than Article that have properties which are translations...

Comment: I have updated with a TranslatableProperty which does the translation and holds the translations.

Comment: V2 works, thanks! The problem is that it changes the Article model structure, adding the propTranslation property. I use this model to upload it to an API with an specific structure, which would be broken.

Comment: @Pizzicato Then you have to add a constructor to the original Article model that gets a new Article model (with the TranslatableProperties) as a parameter and convert what you want. As Translate holds only one language and text properties there's no other way you can touch outside and search other properties on the same level.

Comment: All right, thanks, @Perrier. I think I'll just make a `util.js` file where I'll add a function that receives a Translation array and a language and returns the right text. What you suggest gets too complicated, although is correct! :-)

Answer (score 0):

At runtime there is only one `Array` class so adding a method for one type of array will add it for all types which can lead to conflicts. That being said you can add the method for just one Typescript array type like so

```
class Article {
    constructor(public name: Translation[]) { }
}

class Translation {
    constructor(
        public language: string,
        public text: string
    ) { }
}

interface Array<T> { // this has to be in global of în a module
    translate(this: Translation[], lang: string): string;
}

Array.prototype.translate = function (lang) {
    var t = this.find(o => o.language == lang);
    return t && t.text;

}

let article = new Article([

]);
article.name.translate('EN')
```

Comment: It works, but I think @Perrier answer is better because of the possible namespacing conflicts.

Comment: @Pizzicato sure his solution makes good sense. The question was very specific about extending array, that is what I provided, I didn't think of an alternative way to approach the problem. This is why I caveated the answer with the conflict issue, sometimes just because we can do it does not mean we should :-)

Comment: Yes, I agree! Thanks, @Titian!